# Windows Phone & WCF

Tags: wcf, windows-phone

Using this tutorial: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/UrmimalaPal/creating-a-windows-phone-7-application-consuming-data-using-a-wcf-service/

I have created sample/hello world application on the windows phone which basically gets data from a SQL Server. I am using the Emulator in Visual Studio and WCF to connect the mobile phone to the server.

What I want to do now is improve this simple application so that it is not on *localhost*. I want my WCF running on my machine, install the application on my actual phone and then, like, go outside my house and still get data from the server.

So Basically, I'm going to improve it so it doesn't just work locally, but via a connection from my mobile to the server and not just on the emulator.

Any ideas?

(Sorry for my excessive explaining. I'm new to C# and Windows Mobile so I apologise if i'm being silly).

Thank you.

Comment: First, is your computer accessible away from home?  Can you reach the default IIS page?  http:  //your.ip.address?  Remember, your ISP probably gives you a dynamic IP address to discourage stuff like this from going on...

Comment: Nope I can't do http : //my.ip.address

Comment: So ya gotta figure that out first.  Your ISP may be blocking port 80.  Do some Googling around sharing IIS apps from home computers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, I simply made a normal WCF console application and ran it as a service using interfaces and applying them to services.

I was then able to see this service running in Windows.